# Run Two Modules in Different Directories in Java 11

Tags: java, module, java-11

Directories Structure :

[image: Directories Structure]

After compilation if i store two module in two different directories[out, out2].

When I'm try to combine two module out and out2 with : operator in java command.

```
java --upgrade-module-path out:out2 -m myModuleA/myPackA.ClassA
```

when i try this command throw the error.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: out:out2
```

Please Suggest me Where is my Mistake.I'm newbie in (Java Modules).

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem ?

Comment: yes i find this solve

Comment: can you please share your solution

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624)

--upgrade-module-path modulepath...
Searches for directories from a semicolon-separated (;) list of directories. Each directory is a directory of modules that replace upgradeable modules in the runtime image.

`out:out2`  should be `out;out2`