# Error: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext (Command Line)

Tags: java, jaxb

**Context:** I am executing a (third party) jar file from Command Line. The program executes. But when I click a button in the program it results in an error. (Using JDK - 15, JavaFX-15).

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
```

To execute from command line I am using the below (launches the program):

```
java -jar --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml programName.jar
```

**Research:** Based on these links - [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069702/java-command-line-with-external-jar) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295122/run-two-modules-in-different-directories-in-java-11) & few more in this forum,

I realize that I need to include jaxb jar in the command line. I have downloaded jaxb-api.jar from Maven & kept it in c:\Jar_Files\jaxb-api.jar

I am unable to figure out how I should include the jaxb-api in the command line so that the program does not throw an error when I click the button.

Hope the issue faced is clear, await inputs.

Comment: That probably means that the third party jar was not meant to run above JDK11 when JEE/CORBA packages were removed. Does including it in classpath fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download one of the jakarta bind libs. eg. Maven GAVC: jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3

```
# Downloading libs from maven central
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
java -cp jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar -jar --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,java.xml,java.xml.bind,jakarta.activation programName.jar
```

Comment: tried the above, but still the same error, any other way?

Comment: Try adding the module java.xml.bind. Updated my answer

Comment: When I enter the above edited suggestion in Command line, it returns an error java.lang.module.FindException: Module jakarta.activation not found

Comment: Yes, I expected that and had updated my answer. Can you just not use the modules? Would make life much easier

Comment: Which modules I should not use? If I do not specify javafx.controls, javafx.fxml modules then the program will not execute saying JavaFx runtime components are missing. I used your latest revision, even then get the error. Guess am missing something here

Answer (score 0):

The jaxb-api is not enough. You also need the jaxb-runtime.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb-runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I guess you missed my query. It is about how I need to specify the inclusion of jaxb in 'Command Line' as it is a 3rd party JAR file & not a program which I am writing. So adding dependency is not possible.